Advice on solving an "Extended" Confluent Hypergeometric equation
I have an equation of this form:
$$ z \frac{d^2 f}{dz^2} + \left(\frac{-1}{2}-z\right) \frac{df}{dz}+\left( \frac{1-q}{4}- \frac{\epsilon \ a}{4 q^2}z - \frac{\epsilon \ (a+q^2)}{4 q^3} z^2 - \frac{\epsilon}{4 q^2} z^3 \right) f = 0$$
where $q, a, \epsilon$ are constants, and $\epsilon \ll 1$. I'm looking for the local asymptotic behavior of $f(z)$ as $z \to \infty$. If $\epsilon = 0$, this fits exactly the form of the confluent hypergeometric equation and the solution is known.
I have only seen 1 paper by Campos 2001 (found here) that classifies this as the "Extended Confluent Hypergeometric equation" (of degree 3) but only talks about special cases and I've found nothing else like it.
I'm wondering if there's any transformation I can try to simplify this any further or if there's any other known special functions that fit this form? Perhaps there's a transformation into Heun's equation? But my equation has an irregular singular point of higher rank than 3.
I thought about attempting an integral representation of the solution but my coefficients are not linear functions of $z$, so this wouldn't lead to simplification. My next step would be to try to find the leading order behavior around $z = \infty$ letting $f(z) = e^{S(z)}$, and finding $S(z)$ by dominant balance arguments. Casting this into normal form and attempting WKB might also be an option.
I'm open to any ideas the community has. Thank you!

This paper might be useful. You will get different large $z$ asymptotics for $\epsilon=0$ and $\epsilon\ne 0$. I am not sure how to obtain a uniform asymptotic approximation.
